The following assertion was thrown building _FocusInheritedScope(dirty): 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion:line6216 pos14
When I click addTab, the following error appears on the homePage. If anyone knows what it is, please let me know.
The following assertion was thrown building
_FocusInheritedScope(dirty):


'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed
assertion: line 6216 pos 14: '() {
        // check that it really is our descendant
        Element? ancestor = dependent._parent;
        while (ancestor != this && ancestor != null) {
          ancestor = ancestor._parent;
        }
        return ancestor == this;
      }()': is not true.

Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework
itself, or we should provide substantially
more information in this error message to help you determine
and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug
on GitHub:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bu
g.yml
The relevant error-causing widget was:
  MaterialApp
  MaterialApp:file:///Users/harumi/flutter_project/flutter_pr
  oject/memoone/lib/main.dart:183:12

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#2      InheritedElement.notifyClients
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6216:14)
#3      _InheritedNotifierElement.notifyClients
(package:flutter/src/widgets/inherited_notifier.dart:123:11)
#4      _InheritedNotifierElement.build
(package:flutter/src/widgets/inherited_notifier.dart:111:7)
#5      ComponentElement.performRebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5617:15)
#6      Element.rebuild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5333:7)
#7      ProxyElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5946:5)
#8      _InheritedNotifierElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/inherited_notifier.dart:105:11)
#9      Element.updateChild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3941:15)
#10     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6907:14)
#11     Element.updateChild
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3941:15)

Another exception was thrown:
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed
assertion: line 6216 pos 14: '() {
Another exception was thrown:
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed
assertion: line 6216 pos 14: '() {
Bad state: Cannot use "ref" after the widget was disposed.
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      ConsumerStatefulElement._assertNotDisposed
(package:flutter_riverpod/src/consumer.dart:550:7)
#1      ConsumerStatefulElement.watch
(package:flutter_riverpod/src/consumer.dart:556:5)
#2      HomePageState.dispose
(package:memoone/screen/home_page.dart:43:9)
#3      StatefulElement.unmount
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5826:11)
#4      ConsumerStatefulElement.unmount
(package:flutter_riverpod/src/consumer.dart:575:11)
#5      _InactiveElements._unmount
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2077:13)
#6      _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2075:7)
#7      ComponentElement.visitChildren
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5669:14)
#8      _InactiveElements._unmount
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2073:13)
#9      _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2075:7)
#10     ComponentElement.visitChildren
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5669:14)
#11     _InactiveElements._unmount
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2073:13)
#12     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2075:7)
#13     ComponentElement.visitChildren
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5669:14)
#14     _InactiveElements._unmount
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2073:13)
#15     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2075:7)
#16     ComponentElement.visitChildren
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5669:14)
#17     _InactiveElements._unmount
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2073:13)
#18     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2075:7)
#19     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6998:16)
#20     _InactiveElements._unmount
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2073:13)
#21     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2075:7)
#22     ComponentElement.visitChildren
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5669:14)
#23     _InactiveElements._unmount
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2073:13)
#24     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2075:7)
#25     ComponentElement.visitChildren
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5669:14)
#26     _InactiveElements._unmount
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2073:13)
#27     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2075:7)
#28     ComponentElement.visitChildren
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5669:14)
#29     _InactiveElements._unmount
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2073:13)
#30     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2075:7)
#31     ComponentElement.visitChildren
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5669:14)
#32     _InactiveElements._unmount
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2073:13)
(elided 3 frames from class _Timer and dart:async-patch)

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:memoone/components/provider/auth_provider.dart';
import 'package:memoone/components/provider/tab_state_notifier.dart';
import 'package:memoone/components/widgets/tab_widget.dart';
import 'package:memoone/screen/all_tab.dart';
import 'package:memoone/screen/memo_enter.dart';
import 'package:memoone/screen/settings_page.dart';
import 'package:memoone/utility/signup_login_tab.dart';

class HomePage extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  HomePageState createState() => HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends ConsumerState<HomePage>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    final tabState = ref.watch(tabStateProvider);

    // TabControllerの初期化
    if (tabState.tabController == null) {
      final tabController = TabController(
        length: tabState.tabs.length,
        vsync: this,
      );

      ref.watch(tabStateProvider.notifier).updateTabs(
            tabState.tabs,
            tabState.tabViews,
            tabController,
          );
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    ref.watch(tabStateProvider.notifier).disposeTabController();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final authState = ref.watch(authStateProvider);
    final tabState = ref.watch(tabStateProvider);

    return authState.when(
        data: (user) {
          if (user == null) {
            return const Scaffold(
              body: SignUpLoginPage(),
            );
          }
          return Scaffold(
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
            appBar: AppBar(
              leading: IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.settings),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                    return const SettingsPage();
                  }));
                },
              ),
              automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
              bottom:
                  tabState.tabController != null && tabState.tabViews.isNotEmpty
                      ? TabBar(
                          tabAlignment: TabAlignment.center,
                          isScrollable: true,
                          controller: tabState.tabController,
                          tabs: tabState.tabs,
                        )
                      : const Tab(
                          text: '全て',
                        ),
              actions: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    await addTab(ref, this, context);
                  }, // タブを追加する処理
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                      return const TabManagementScreen();
                    }));
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
            body: tabState.tabController != null && tabState.tabViews.isNotEmpty
                ? TabBarView(
                    controller: tabState.tabController,
                    children: tabState.tabViews,
                  )
                : const Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      SizedBox(height: 20),
                      Text('タブの読み込みに失敗しました。もう一度お試しください。'),
                    ],
                  ),
            floatingActionButtonLocation:
                FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
            floatingActionButton: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 80,
                height: 56,
                child: FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    final auth = ref.watch(firebaseAuthProvider);
                    if (auth.currentUser == null) {
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                        const SnackBar(
                          content: Text('新規登録又はログインしてください'),
                        ),
                      );
                      Navigator.push(context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                        return const SignUpLoginPage();
                      }));
                      return;
                    }
                    // 現在のタブのカテゴリを取得
                    if (tabState.tabController != null &&
                        tabState.tabs.isNotEmpty) {
                      final currentIndex = tabState.tabController!.index;
                      final category =
                          (tabState.tabs[currentIndex] as Tab).text ?? 'all';

                      Navigator.push(context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                        return MemoEnterPage(
                          category: category,
                        );
                      }));
                    }
                  },
                  child: const Icon(Icons.add),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        loading: () => const Scaffold(
              body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
            ),
        error: (err, stack) =>
            Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text('Error: $err'))));
  }
}

import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:app_links/app_links.dart';
import 'package:app_tracking_transparency/app_tracking_transparency.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:memoone/components/provider/analytics_firebase.dart';
import 'package:memoone/components/provider/auth_provider.dart';
import 'package:memoone/firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:memoone/repository/auth_repository.dart';
import 'package:memoone/screen/detail_summary_page.dart';
import 'package:memoone/state/widget_update.dart';
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;

final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  tz.initializeTimeZones();
  tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation("Asia/Tokyo"));

  print("Firebaseとタイムゾーンの初期化が完了しました。");

  const DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS =
      DarwinInitializationSettings();

  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  const InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
      InitializationSettings(iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.requestPermissions(
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true,
      );

  final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final user = auth.currentUser;

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
    initializationSettings,
    onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: onDidReceiveNotificationResponse,
    onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse:
        onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse,
  );

  print("通知の初期化が完了しました。");

  // 通知からアプリが起動された場合の処理
  final NotificationAppLaunchDetails? notificationAppLaunchDetails =
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();
  String? payload = notificationAppLaunchDetails?.notificationResponse?.payload;

  runApp(ProviderScope(child: MyApp(initialPayload: payload)));
}

class MyApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  MyApp({
    super.key,
    this.initialPayload,
  });
  final String? initialPayload;

  Future<void> showAppTrackingTransparencyDialog() async {
    final status = await AppTrackingTransparency.trackingAuthorizationStatus;
    if (status == TrackingStatus.notDetermined) {
      await AppTrackingTransparency.requestTrackingAuthorization();
    }
  }

  final bool initialized = true;
  final AppLinks appLinks = AppLinks();
  final WidgetUpdater widgetUpdater = WidgetUpdater();

  // フラグを追加
  bool isProcessingDeeplink = false;

  // WidgetUpdater インスタンスを作成

  void scheduleDailyNotification() async {
    final now = tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local);
    var scheduledTime = tz.TZDateTime(
      tz.local,
      now.year,
      now.month,
      now.day,
      9,
      8,
      0,
    );

    print("通知のスケジュール時間: $scheduledTime");

    final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final user = auth.currentUser;

    final snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('summary')
        .doc(user!.uid)
        .collection("summaries")
        .get();

    print("Firestoreからデータを取得しました。ドキュメント数: ${snapshot.docs.length}");

    if (snapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
      // ドキュメントリストを取得
      final docs = snapshot.docs.toList();

      // ドキュメントリストをシャッフル
      docs.shuffle();
      final data = docs.first.data();

      const title = '今日の要約はこちら！';
      final content = data['summary_content'] ?? '内容';

      // Timestampを変換
      data.forEach((key, value) {
        if (value is Timestamp) {
          data[key] = value.toDate().toIso8601String();
        }
      });

      await FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin().zonedSchedule(
        0,
        title,
        content,
        scheduledTime,
        const NotificationDetails(
          iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails(),
        ),
        uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
            UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.wallClockTime,
        matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.time,
        payload: jsonEncode(data),
      );
      print("通知がスケジュールされました。タイトル: $title, 内容: $content");
    } else {
      print("Firestoreに一致するドキュメントがありません。");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final auth = ref.watch(firebaseAuthProvider);
    final userAsyncValue = ref.watch(authStateProvider);

    // ディープリンクのリスナーは1回のみ設定
    appLinks.uriLinkStream.listen((Uri? uri) {
      if (uri != null && !isProcessingDeeplink) {
        // 処理開始時にフラグを立てる
        isProcessingDeeplink = true;
        print("ディープリンクが受信されました: $uri");
        widgetUpdater.handleDeeplinkNavigation(uri, ref).then((_) {
          // 処理完了後にフラグを戻す
          isProcessingDeeplink = false;
        });
      } else {
        print("無効なディープリンクが受信されました");
      }
    });

    Future.microtask(() async {
      await showAppTrackingTransparencyDialog();
    });
    scheduleDailyNotification();
    widgetUpdater.updateWidgetWithSummary(ref);

    var analytics = ref.watch(analyticsRepository);
    var analyticsObserver = ref.watch(analyticsObserverRepository);
    analytics.logAppOpen();
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          if (initialPayload != null) {
            WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
              handleNotificationTap(initialPayload!);
            });
          }
          return AuthWrapper();
        },
      ),
      navigatorObservers: [analyticsObserver],
    );
  }
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse(
    NotificationResponse response) async {
  if (response.payload != null) {
    handleNotificationTap(response.payload!);
  }
}

void onDidReceiveNotificationResponse(NotificationResponse response) {
  if (response.payload != null) {
    handleNotificationTap(response.payload!);
  }
}

Future<void> handleNotificationTap(
  String payload,
) async {
  final data = jsonDecode(payload);

  final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('summary')
      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
      .collection('summaries')
      .doc(data['memoId'])
      .get();

  navigatorKey.currentState?.push(
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => DetailSummaryPage(
        memo: documentSnapshot,
      ),
    ),
  );
}

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:flutter_slidable/flutter_slidable.dart';
import 'package:memoone/components/provider/auth_provider.dart';
import 'package:memoone/components/provider/bookmark_provider.dart';
import 'package:memoone/components/provider/tab_state_notifier.dart';
import 'package:memoone/screen/detail_bookmark_page.dart';
import 'package:memoone/screen/detail_page.dart';
import 'package:memoone/screen/detail_summary_page.dart';

Future<void> addTab(
    WidgetRef ref, TickerProvider vsync, BuildContext context) async {
  final auth = ref.watch(firebaseAuthProvider);
  final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

  final newTabName = await showDialog<String>(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: const Text('新しいタブの名前を入力してください'),
        content: TextField(
          controller: controller,
          decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'タブの名前'),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop(null); // キャンセルした場合
            },
            child: const Text('キャンセル'),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop(controller.text); // 入力されたテキストを返す
            },
            child: const Text('保存'),
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );

  if (newTabName != null && newTabName.isNotEmpty) {
    final newTabOrder = ref.watch(tabStateProvider).tabs.length;

    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(auth.currentUser!.uid)
        .collection('tabs')
        .add({
      'name': newTabName,
      'order': newTabOrder,
    });

    await loadTabs(ref, vsync);

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      ref.watch(tabStateProvider.notifier).disposeTabController();

      final tabState = ref.watch(tabStateProvider);
      final newTabController = TabController(
        length: tabState.tabs.length,
        vsync: vsync,
      );

      ref.watch(tabStateProvider.notifier).updateTabs(
            tabState.tabs,
            tabState.tabViews,
            newTabController,
          );
    });
  }
}

Future<void> deleteTab(
    WidgetRef ref, String tabId, TickerProvider vsync) async {
  final auth = ref.watch(firebaseAuthProvider);

  try {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(auth.currentUser!.uid)
        .collection('tabs')
        .where('name', isEqualTo: tabId)
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) {
      for (var doc in snapshot.docs) {
        doc.reference.delete();
      }
    });

    ref.watch(tabStateProvider.notifier).removeTab(tabId, vsync);

    await loadTabs(ref, vsync); // タブを再読み込み
    Future.microtask(
        () => loadSummaryTabs(ref, vsync)); // SummaryPage用のタブをリフレッシュ
    Future.microtask(
        () => loadBookmarkTabs(ref, vsync)); // BookmarkList用のタブをリフレッシュ
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error deleting tab: $e');
  }
}

Future<void> loadTabs(WidgetRef ref, TickerProvider vsync) async {
  final auth = ref.watch(firebaseAuthProvider);
  final snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .doc(auth.currentUser!.uid)
      .collection('tabs')
      .orderBy('order')
      .get();

  final userTabs = snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
    return {'name': doc['name'] as String, 'category': doc['name'] as String};
  }).toList();

  final allTabs = [
        {'name': '全て', 'category': 'all'}
      ] +
      userTabs;

  final tabs = allTabs.map((tab) {
    return Tab(text: tab['name']);
  }).toList();

  final tabViews = allTabs.map((tab) {
    return buildMemoList(tab['category']!, ref);
  }).toList();

  final tabController = TabController(length: tabs.length, vsync: vsync);

  ref
      .watch(tabStateProvider.notifier)
      .updateTabs(tabs, tabViews, tabController);
}

Widget buildMemoList(String category, WidgetRef ref) {
  final auth = ref.watch(firebaseAuthProvider);
  Query memosQuery = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .doc(auth.currentUser!.uid)
      .collection('memos');

  if (category != 'all') {
    memosQuery = memosQuery.where('category', isEqualTo: category);
  }

  return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: memosQuery.orderBy('timestamp', descending: true).snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        print("Error: ${snapshot.error}");
        return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
      } else {
        final memos = snapshot.data!.docs;

        if (memos.isEmpty) {
          return const Center(
            child: Text(
              '読書や仕事の整理に！',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          );
        }

        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: memos.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final memo = memos[index];
            final itemId = memos[index].id;
            final item = memos[index].data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

            return SizedBox(
              height: 100,
              child: Card(
                  child: Slidable(
                key: ValueKey(memo.id),
                endActionPane: ActionPane(
                  motion: const ScrollMotion(),
                  children: [
                    SlidableAction(
                      onPressed: (context) async {
                        showDialog(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (BuildContext context) {
                            return AlertDialog(
                              title: const Text('削除しますか？'),
                              actions: [
                                TextButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    Navigator.pop(context);
                                  },
                                  child: const Text('キャンセル'),
                                ),
                                TextButton(
                                  onPressed: () async {
                                    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                        .collection('users')
                                        .doc(auth.currentUser!.uid)
                                        .collection('memos')
                                        .doc(memo.id)
                                        .delete();
                                    print("削除しました");
                                    Navigator.pop(context);
                                  },
                                  child: const Text('削除'),
                                ),
                              ],
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                      foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                      icon: Icons.delete,
                      label: '削除',
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    memo['title'],
                    maxLines: 1,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  subtitle: Text(
                    memo['content'],
                    maxLines: 2,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                      return DetailPage(
                        memo: memo,
                        // category: memo['category'],
                      );
                    }));
                  },
                ),
              )),
            );
          },
        );
      }
    },
  );
}

import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TabState {
  final List<Widget> tabs;
  final List<Widget> tabViews;
  TabController? tabController;

  TabState({required this.tabs, required this.tabViews, this.tabController});

  TabState copyWith({
    List<Widget>? tabs,
    List<Widget>? tabViews,
    TabController? tabController,
  }) {
    return TabState(
      tabs: tabs ?? this.tabs,
      tabViews: tabViews ?? this.tabViews,
      tabController: tabController ?? this.tabController,
    );
  }
}

class TabStateNotifier extends StateNotifier<TabState> {
  TabStateNotifier()
      : super(TabState(tabs: [], tabViews: [], tabController: null));

  void updateTabs(
      List<Widget> tabs, List<Widget> tabViews, TabController tabController) {
    state = state.copyWith(
        tabs: tabs, tabViews: tabViews, tabController: tabController);
  }

  void disposeTabController() {
    state.tabController?.dispose();
    state = state.copyWith(tabController: null); // 破棄後にnullを設定
  }

  void removeTab(String tabText, TickerProvider vsync) {
    final index = state.tabs.indexWhere((tab) {
      if (tab is Tab) {
        return tab.text == tabText;
      }
      return false;
    });

    if (index != -1) {
      final updatedTabs = List<Widget>.from(state.tabs)..removeAt(index);
      final updatedTabViews = List<Widget>.from(state.tabViews)
        ..removeAt(index);

      final updatedTabController = TabController(
        length: updatedTabs.length,
        vsync: vsync,
        initialIndex:
            state.tabController!.index.clamp(0, updatedTabs.length - 1),
      );

      state = state.copyWith(
        tabs: updatedTabs,
        tabViews: updatedTabViews,
        tabController: updatedTabController,
      );

      // 古いTabControllerを破棄
      state.tabController?.dispose();
    }
  }
}

final tabStateProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<TabStateNotifier, TabState>((ref) {
  return TabStateNotifier();
});

I've tried rewriting various other codes, but it's not working.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
